# Can't start my JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, function

I want to get random hashtag from array, but the function is not working. This is my code:

```
function hashtagfunc(){
  var hashtags = ["#beginner", "#webdev", "#creator"];
  var tag = hashtags[Math.floor(Math.random() * myArray.length)];
  document.getElementById("hashtag").innerHTML = hashtags;
}
```

I have the element and id on it.

Comment: What calls the function?  Also the last line of the function should assign `tag` to the `.innerHTML`, not `hashtags`.

Comment: @Pointy i want the paragraph in body (with id hashtag) to change text every load, automatically. And i tried to run it in chrome console, function now working.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the wrong name for the array when creating the random number. It should be:

```
var tag = hashtags[Math.floor(Math.random() * hashtags.length)];
```

Then you should use that variable in the next statement:

```
document.getElementById("hashtag").innerHTML = tag;
```

Comment: Thanks, my fault,, i didnt see it. **Working**.